# using querySelectorAll after getElementById not working in javascript

Tags: html, css

I have a lot of elements I color them with `querySelectorAll` Then I want to color one of the elements with `getElementById` Then I use `querySelectorAll` it again to color all the elements again ,The problem is the second time it does not work (the color is not changed with `querySelectorAll`).

There are other ways to do something like this `getElementsByClassName` But I want to work with the idea of the above method
The code explains the question more:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="main">
<h2 class="ex" id="myH1">This is an example h2</h2>
<h2 class="ex" id="myH2">This is an example h2</h2>
<h2 class="ex" id="myH3">This is an example h2</h2>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Set text color all</button>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction2()">Set text color one</button>

<script>
function myFunction2() {
 var x = document.querySelectorAll(".main");
 var i; 
    for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
      {
       x[i].style.color = "#00ff88"; 
      }
}

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myH2").style.color = "#ff0000";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please click on **Set text color all** first, then click on **Set text color one** the click on **Set text color all** again.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with JavaScript. You’re essentially doing `<div class="main" style="color: green;"><h2 style="color: red;">Text</h2></div>` and are asking why `Text` is red instead of green. This is only about CSS and CSS property inheritance. Please [edit] your post and provide a [mre] that focuses on that, i.e. remove all the JS because that’s not relevant.

Comment: Also, your buttons are executing wrong functions...

Comment: @SebastianSimon Hello sir, why does it have nothing to do with javascript, I want to do this using javascript, make a color with an identifier and then with querySelectorAll it does not work but in css everything works fine

Comment: @mody no with CSS you would have the exact same problem because `var x = document.querySelectorAll(".main");` is the `div.main` and not children! `x.length` will also just be only ONE item, the div. You can debug your CSS after your javascript function calls, then you will see the applied styles on each element, as they really are.

Comment: @mody This is fundamentally a CSS inheritance issue. You can reproduce the same behavior without JS. Once you understand the relevant [CSS inheritance](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance) rules, you should be able to see how to apply this knowledge to JS. The [dev tools](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) provide an **Inspector** / **Elements** tab which is helpful here. Inspect your elements. See what the inspector reveals about the applied CSS rules.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Yes of course, but I do not have enough information in css. I am a java programmer and I need some code for css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the `h2` also in the selector  like:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".main h2"); // add h2 here in the
```

and then the color will be set on the "same" element's always and your CSS will work. The problem you are facing is (as Sebastian mentioned in the comment) that you set the color one time on the `<div class="main"...` and another time on the `<h2 id="myH2"...`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="main">
<h2 class="ex" id="myH1">This is an example h2</h2>
<h2 class="ex" id="myH2">This is an example h2</h2>
<h2 class="ex" id="myH3">This is an example h2</h2>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction2()">Set text color all</button>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Set text color one</button>

<script>
function myFunction2() {
 var x = document.querySelectorAll(".main h2"); // add h2 here in the selector
 var i; 
    for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
      {
       x[i].style.color = "#00ff88"; 
      }
}

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myH2").style.color = "#ff0000";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You mean `querySelectorAll` doesn't work , should be customized more like main>h1(deep)?

Comment: @mody No, I'm absolutely sure that `querySelectorAll` works perfectly fine! How you used the selector inside `querySelectorAll(selector)` was/is wrong. Try `console.log(x.length, x)` after `var x = document.querySelectorAll(".main");` and then do it again with `var x = document.querySelectorAll(".main h2");` what is the difference?

Comment: Thank you, the problem has been resolved, for caution, I use `span` instead of `h` and it works too